# cmake spaces for the solution file

Tags: cmake

line of space is not provided by the cmake with file of "putthis" ,but expected is "put this"

Comment: It's `set_target_properties(EDDEngine PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "EDD Engine")` EDDEngine is not a variable, just the target name.

Comment: You can't. Target name can't have spaces. You can set the output_name to have spaces, so the ending library file is `libEDD Engine.so`.

Comment: Why have you invalidated the question with removing the code and its description?

Comment: some issue with the question bro,sorry.